# Multi channel audio iOS (need 4 simultaneous inputs)

Tags: ios, audio, ios6, core-audio, remoteio

I am working on a project where I need to process 4 audio input streams simultaneously. So far, I have been working using stereo audio streams, where the data originates from a USB based audio device designed specifically for iOS, like the Tascam iM2.

- Does iOS 6 support more an 2 channels of simultaneous input?
- If so, what devices are available for this?

EDIT: 
I have seen that the 4-channel Apogee quartet is compatible with iOS. Is it possible to record 4 channels of audio simultaneously using this device?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? The link in the answer no longer works..

Answer (score 0):

I worked on a similar project this past summer and, if I remember correctly, you need to use Audio Queue Services if you want to process multiple streams concurrently.

It is something of a beast to work with and is not very well documented.

If you can deal with some early-stage code, I wrote a sample project that does that plays sounds with Audio Queue Services (https://github.com/acopp/Streamer/tree/master/Streamer). You will obviously need to tweak it but I believe it is a good starting point.